# Regex django url

Tags: python, regex, django

Hello I have a url and I want to match the uuid
the url looks like this:

> /mobile/mobile-thing/**68f8ffbb-b715-46fb-90f8-b474d9c57134/**

```
urlpatterns = patterns("mobile.views",
    url(r'^$', 'something_cool', name='cool'),
    url(r'^mobile-thing/(?P<uuid>[.*/])$', 'mobile_thing', name='mobile-thinger'),
)
```

but this doesn't work at all. My corresponding view is not being called. I tested so many variations...*ahw*

but `url(r'^mobile-thing/', 'mobile_thing', name='mobile-thinger')` works like a charm but no group...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `[.*/]` expression only matches **one** character, which can be `.`, `*` or `/`. You need to write instead (this is just one of many options):

```
urlpatterns = patterns("mobile.views",
    url(r'^$', 'something_cool', name='cool'),
    url(r'^mobile-thing/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)/$', 'mobile_thing', name='mobile-thinger'),
)
```

Here, `[^/]` represents any character but `/`, and the `+` right after matches this class of character one or more times. You do not want the final `/` to be in the `uuid` var, so put it outside the parentheses.

Comment: thanks a lot...this does not call my view function...i also tried so many variations...could it be a problem that this urls are included into another urls?

Comment: *How* is it being included? Show that code. The problem is almost certainly there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex instead:

```
\/mobile-thing\/(?P<uuid>.*)\/$
```

So it'd be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("mobile.views",
    url(r'^$', 'something_cool', name='cool'),
    url(r'\/mobile-thing\/(?P<uuid>.*)\/$', 'mobile_thing', name='mobile-thinger'),
)
```

Comment: thanks..i missed to say that the regex is insite of an included url...this does matter does it?

Comment: ".*" is all characters and will include "/" when it is not the ending character. So "/asdffadd/asdfdfsadf/" = "asdffadd/asdfdfsadf"