# ManyToManyField references the 'id' field when using a custom primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using a custom primary key for a model that has a few ManyToManyFields. When I update the model and add an object to a ManyToManyField (using add(new_object)), I get an error signifying that its looking up the primary key using the `id` field (which perhaps exists in the intermediary table, but not in the model).

```
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "TL98GK"
LINE 1: ...WHERE ("placedir_place_place_categ"."place_id" = 'TL98GK' A...
```

I have been searching on SO for a while but havent been able to zero in the exact issue. I guess I may have to use custom through table for ManytoManyFields (as a punishment for using custom primary key) but I honestly dont want to go down that route.

Using Django 1.10 and Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the migration doesn't detect Foreign Key type changes well. It's a known [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25012). A workaround is mentioned [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25012#comment:8) (i.e to explicitly change the field `type` to `varchar(32)`).

However, you may need to do more (like updating the `constraints` etc. on the table) depending on your use case. (For those interested to go that route, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33825801/1526703) is one example case with corresponding migration code).

(p.s I just decided to not use a custom primary key on models with manytomany fields)